# The installation of mongodb has broken my package manager

Tags: mongodb, installation

I'm a bit disappointed! I wanted to install mongodb by following the official documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/

But, firstly it did not install, and then, my package manager is broken, I can not do any more update!

J'ai tenté ces commandes :

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt purge mongodb 
sudo apt-get remove mongodb-org-server
apt-get -reinstall install mongodb
```

I tried all the commands I could find on the internet, and nothing to do, it still does not work!

Here is the error when trying to update:

```
Err :12 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease 
  Le fichier signé en clair n'est pas valable, ce qui a été reçu est « NOSPLIT ». Peut-être le réseau nécessite-t-il une authentification.
Réception de :35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [209 kB]
Réception de :36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42,0 kB]
Réception de :37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16,4 kB]
Réception de :38 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [116 kB]
Réception de :39 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 464 B]
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait                                     
E: Impossible de récupérer http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/InRelease  Le fichier signé en clair n'est pas valable, ce qui a été reçu est « NOSPLIT ». Peut-être le réseau nécessite-t-il une authentification.
E: Le dépôt http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease n'est pas signé.
N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut.
N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
```

Can someone help me find a solution? It's been two days that I'm looking for, I'm running out of ideas :(

thank you for your attention :)

Isaure

Comment: Did you manage to install other packages before mongodb? Are you behind a company proxy ?

Comment: Hello ! Yes, I have always been able to install things without problems. I work in a development school, and no, normally. It's really just because some dependencies are not installed properly, but I can not uninstall them to finish uninstalling mongodb cleanly.